# Create a notification on android from a remote server

Tags: android, notifications

I have a server and I wish to have it send a notification to my phone every time a certain event occurs.  However I would rather it not email or text me.  Is there anyway to create a notification remotely from a server on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Set XMPP service on your server or use someone's else server and send notification over it with help of `sendxmpp` utility as

```
echo "Super Notification" | sendxmpp -s Notification owner@myserver.tld
```

Use some XMPP client on android to receive it, [Xabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android&hl=en) is my favorite.